# GET request response express.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, get

I'm Trying to send a GET req to my express server and logging it to the console using

```js
const get = document.getElementById("getData");
      get.addEventListener('click', getData)
      
const myRequest = new Request('/url here/', {
  method: 'GET',
});

function getData () { fetch(myRequest)
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  };
```

but getting this(below) as the result and not the mongoose database array expected. what am i missing?

```js
Response {type: "basic", url: "url here", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}body: (...)bodyUsed: falseheaders: Headers {}ok: trueredirected: falsestatus: 200statusText: ""type: "basic"url: "url here/"__proto__: ResponsearrayBuffer: ƒ arrayBuffer()blob: ƒ blob()arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 0name: "blob"__proto__: ƒ ()[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]body: (...)bodyUsed: (...)clone: ƒ clone()formData: ƒ formData()headers: (...)json: ƒ json()ok: (...)redirected: (...)status: (...)statusText: (...)text: ƒ text()type: (...)url: (...)constructor: ƒ Response()Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Response"get body: ƒ body()get bodyUsed: ƒ bodyUsed()get headers: ƒ headers()get ok: ƒ ok()get redirected: ƒ redirected()get status: ƒ status()get statusText: ƒ statusText()get type: ƒ type()get url: ƒ url()__proto__: Object
```

Here's the route:

````js
router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  variable.find()
    .then(variable => res.json(variable))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});```
````

Comment: To get the body from a request using `fetch()`, you have to do `response.json()` or `response.text()` and then use `await` or `.then()` on that promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to use response.json() to get data

```
const get = document.getElementById("getData");
          get.addEventListener('click', getData)
          
    const myRequest = new Request('/url here/');
    
    async function getData () { 
    
    await fetch(request, {
          method: "GET"
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log("Fail zone");
        })
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.ok) {
            res.json().then((json) => {
             console.log(json)
            });
          } else {
            console.log("error", res);
          }
        });
      };
```

for reference you can check this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmanii/ydfqk314/4/)